# How can I make properties optionally Read-Only or settable in various related classes?

Tags: c#, properties

In my project, I am creating generic interfaces to be used by a number of classes.  This includes some properties that must always be present.

Some of the classes will be generic, and therefore the property must be changeable at run-time.  Some of the classes will be highly specialized, and therefore, the value of the property will be hard-coded.  I would like to be able to use Bindings in the user interface to display and, where possible, edit the values.  Also, I can imagine that at some point, I would want to use reflection to determine if the properly is settable.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

1)  Define the properties as read-write in the interface, but have an empty setter in the specialized classes.  This appears to be a somewhat common practice, but I am concerned with how binding and reflection would work.  A UI control would still appear editable, just that the change by a user would not take, right?

2)  Define the properties as read-only in the interface, but provide a setter in the generic classes.  I would expect that the UI, bound to use the interface, would still see the property as read-only, and not allow editing.

3)  Define the properties as read-only in the interface, but provide some other function to change the value in generic classes.  This clearly breaks the property paradigm, and a binding wouldn't know about it to allow editing.

Is there some other way to enable or disable the setters that would be recognized by bindings and reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here my 2 cents - you might not like what I am going to say.

If you have a property that is read-only sometimes and read-write other times and constant in the rest, you are having a **leaky abstraction** here were polymorphism probably will only result in confusion to the clients of your classes.

So **either** I would have 2 interfaces one with read-write the other read-only, **or** just *abandon polymorphism* for such properties.

Comment: I actually agree with the leaky abstraction here, which was the reason for my question.  Would I have IMyInterface with the read-only property, and IMyEditableInterface with the same property as read-write, and then implement IMyEditableInterface where I need it?  For the UI, I would probably need to have a different control for the two versions, but that might no be so bad...

Comment: It is very difficult to say without knowing the detail of the Domain. The point is not which abstraction to use, but to use an abstraction which represents your model best. I would say if two interfaces work, then use it. In fact one interface could only contain write-only so if an object implements both then it is read-write...

Comment: Thinking about this more, the read-only use case and read-write use cases are different.  The property is always used for calculation; in certain classes this will be fixed hard or calculated based on other properties.  In the read-write case is to support other cases where the value is constant for calculation purposes, but may be changed by the user.  So, having one standard interface (including the read-only property) for calculation, and a different highly variable interface to support user changes makes sense now.  In this simple case, the two properties could share a backing field.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely only have a getter on the properties in your interface. Having a setter that is not always implemented will only lead to confusion.

You can then implement a setter in the appropriate classes. Depending on your application, you might want to create an extended interface that allows for your property to be set.

Example:

```
    public interface ITest
    {
        int Test { get; }
    }

    public interface ITestExtended : ITest
    {
        new int Test { get; set; }
    }

    public class Monkey : ITestExtended
    {
        public int Test { get; set; }

        // Be carefull to explicitly implement the original interface
        int ITest.Test
        {
            get
            {
                return 7;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MonkeySimple : ITest
    {
        public int Test
        {
            get { return 10; }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ITestExtended monkey = new Monkey() { Test = 5 };
            ITest monkeySimple = monkey;

            Console.WriteLine(monkeySimple.Test);
            Console.WriteLine(monkey.Test);

            // Compiler error
            //monkeySimple.Test = 6;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note:  Both this answer and the one from Aliostad are very similar.  I selected this as the answer for two reasons:  1)  It is more concise and 2) it suggests an extended interface

Comment: I originally accepted this answer, but after progressing, I found some problems.  Perhaps other languages are different, but at least in C# it seems that a setter cannot just be added to an existing read-only property.  Extending this on a subclass leads to problems with polymorphism, as I must define a new getter, and I cannot override the one in the parent class; in some cases I want to.  If I am using the object as the parent type, the getter on the parent class code is called instead getter on the subclass.  This is potentially very dangerous!

Comment: FYI, I still think this was a helpful answer, and I learned a lot from exploring it.  Mainly, I did not realize that interfaces can inherit and be polymorphic - this is incredibly powerful (even though this is evident in the .NET framework).  However, in C# a read-only property cannot be extended to read-write without hiding the original property, and this causes problems.